# Why can't i access objects of a class in C++ like this?

Tags: c++, class, object

So i have a simple class like this:

```
class Tperson
{
 private:
 ...
 public:
 void input(){...}
 void output(){...}
}
```

Inside the main function i created there objects of class Tperson:

```
Tperson p1, p2, p3;
```

Now normally if i wanted to give them values and print them on the screen i would do this:

```
p1.input();
p2.input();
p3.input();
p1.output();
p2.output();
p3.output();
```

But that way i have to type two much and in cases where there're more objects it'd be very inconvinient so i tried this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    pi.input();
    pi.output();
}
```

^ It doesn't work, why is that? And also is there a better way to call input and output for multiple objects of a class, rather than typing them one by one manually?

Comment: There's arrays. containers from the standard library, and probably other things I'm forgetting. And yet, you really think you need this ability?

Comment: @Morchul Sorry, brackets added! Still not work, though.

Comment: ``pi`` is not an object so you can't call `input();` on it. Look at bolov's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<Tperson> persons(3);

for (auto& person : persons)
{
    person.input();
    person.output();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this an [obvious duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202895)? ...